# Moq Verifiable using LINQ syntax

Tags: c#, linq, mocking, moq

I'm using Moq and NUnit to create some tests for a Windows service. I have the following:

```
mockPushService = Mock.Of<IPushService>(m => 
    m.SendPushNotification(It.IsAny<UserDevice>(), It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<int>(), It.IsAny<string>())); // Breaks.

mockMailService = Mock.Of<IEmailService>(m =>
    m.SendMessage(It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<string>()) &&
    m.ThrowErrors == true);
```

`mockMailService` is working fine with the LINQ syntax because the methods aren't void. However, the `mockPushService` isn't working because it's a void method. I know I'm supposed to use `Verifiable`, but I'm not sure how to fit it in using this syntax.

To be more clear, I get this compile-time error:

```
Cannot convert lambda expression to delegate type 'System.Func<SurgeHub.Domain.Services.IPushService,bool>' because some of the return types in the block are not implicitly convertible to the delegate return type

Cannot implicitly convert type 'void' to 'bool'
```

How can I make this work? Thank you.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit on "breaks"? What happens? What is supposed to happen?

Answer (score 3):

I've always used the Moq Setup method. So your first example would become;

```
var push = new Mock<IPushService>();
push.Setup(a => a.SendPushNotification(It.IsAny<UserDevice>(), It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<int>(), It.IsAny<string>()));
```

Likewise your second example, which is working anyway, would be as follows (notice the returns which I assume is a bool)

```
var mail = new Mock<IEmailService>();
mail.Setup(a => a.SendMessage(It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<string>())).Returns(true);
mail.SetupProperty<bool>(a => a.ThrowErrors, true);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use that because the overload expects your method to return bool always. I dont understand a lot of the **Of(T)** method, but i guess you should use setup normaly.